# Syntax error from while loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop, syntax-error

This is my code. I would appreciate any help. I'm getting a syntax error at the "while" line.
It is supposed to do a Verlet approximation of u''(theta)=u(theta)-sqrtu(theta) and then plot u(theta).

```
tlist=[]
ulist=[]
uold=uo
uo= uold-(0.5)[uold+sqrt(uold)]*dt*dt
t=0
tmax=10
dt=.001
while t < tmax
    u,uold=2.0*u-uold-(u+sqrt(u))*dt*dt,u
    t=t+dt
ulist.append(u)
tlist.append(t)
plot(tlist,ulist)'
```

Comment: Please state the programming language of your interest by adding an appropriate tag(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a colon after the while statement.

It should be: `while t < tmax:`

Answer (score 0):

As @Matthias points out, you're missing the : at the end of your `while` statement.

Also, you probably want to lose the `'` after the final call to `plot`.